# Need a simple syntax when using multiple devise user models for the NAV bar, complex conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having trouble with coming up with a simple way to write Ruby conditional for this build case. I have 3 devise user models and based on which user logs in I only want the nag bar to show the correct user class. The idea is to have basically 3 blocks of if else statements which uses the devise user_signed_in? helper as you can see below:

```
<nav class="top-bar">
<section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class="left">
    <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Admin Login Page", admin_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Company Login Page", company_path %></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="right">
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
        <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %></li>


        <% if admin_signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_admin_registration_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Logout", destroy_admin_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
        <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Login", new_admin_session_path %></li>


        <% if company_user_signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_company_user_registration_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Logout", destroy_company_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
        <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Login", new_company_user_session_path %></li>
        <% end %>   
    </ul>
```

The problem is that it doesn't really work like this so the question is twofold. First, how to simply this conditional syntax? Second, how to get it to work?

Comment: What doesn't work about this?  Besides not having `<% end %>` statements for the first two blocks...

Comment: Nick, it will show all 3 logins at the same time rather than just the one that's most relevant.

Comment: Well if you're not logged in, how will it know what login to show?  Is there a way to know if one is going to be a User, Admin or CompanyUser?  Seems like an application-level problem.

Comment: Hi Nick, I was able to find a solution to my problem. Please see my solution code if you're interested. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want an `elsif` here, rather than 3 separate blocks.  Try something to the effect of:

```
if user_signed_in?
  ...
elsif admin_signed_in?
  ...
elsif company_user_signed_in?
  ...
elsif params[:action] == 'index'
  ...
elsif params[:action] == 'admin'
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

or alternatively:

```
if user_signed_in?
  ...
elsif admin_signed_in?
  ...
elsif company_user_signed_in?
  ...
elsif params[:action] == 'index'
  ...
elsif params[:action] == 'admin'
  ...
elsif params[:action] == 'company_user'
  ...
else
  # handle any other case where none of above conditions are met, e.g. params[:action] == 'foobar'
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that's along the same thought I had with the eventual code that used. See my code for explanation.

Comment: No problemo. For future reference, it's a bit of poor form on StackOverflow for you to take someone's answer, re-type it, and then award yourself the correct solution.  If a concept helps you solve your question in the future, you should mark it as the answer rather than re-hashing it.

Comment: That's what I would do if your answer actually helped solve my problem but I solved it with help from other sources.  If you look at my solution, you can see that it's very different than what you wrote even though it has similar ideas. In fact, my original broken code also had the same idea but it doesn't really work.

Comment: Solution looks the same to me, but what do I know about what went through your head.  For what it's worth, your last `else` statement has a condition `params[:action] == 'company_user'` that doesn't do anything.

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what makes the code work. Without it, it would always show you the same and it won't change based on what page you're on.  When you're in the Admin Home page for example, You only want to see admin login, not company or user login. The same with the other two user classes. What makes the code work is first, adding the Case code on top into your controller. The params[:action] in the conditional is for when the user is not logged in to see the correct corresponding user login.

Comment: Sorry but you're wrong on this one. `else params[:action] == 'company_user'` is no different than `else` by itself.

Comment: Well, how does the app know which user login to show? You have 3: users, admin and company users. No one wants all 3 to show up on the page.

Comment: The app doesn't care. Your final `else` statement can only be arrived at if user is not logged in and `params[:action] != 'index'` and `params[:action] != 'admin'`.  This could mean that `params[:action] == 'company_user'`, but it could also mean that `params[:action] == nil` or `params[:action] == 'mighty_morphing_power_rangers'`.  Your final `else` statement will not distinguish between any of these cases.  It's a bug in your code as you have currently written it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean as the code seems to be working. How would you write the code if you had to fix it?

Comment: Remove `params[:action] == 'company_user'` for clarity, and then make the entire thing an `if`/`elsif`/`else` statement with no nesting, as I suggest in my answer above.

Comment: Also, the code is "working" until you come across a case in the future where `params[:action] == nil` and your code handles it in a way that you don't expect.  I would either remove `params[:action] == 'company_user'` for clarity, or I would add a final else statement to catch any unexpected cases.

Comment: I just tried your first method and it seems to works as well. I can see why you chose to refactor it. It's cleaner. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution for my problem. I will post the solution in the hopes that it will help someone else out later if/when they're looking to solve the same problem. This is for Rails 4 btw.

First, you need to put the following in the applications_controller.rb file.

```
 def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 case resource
 when User then '/'
 when Admin then '/admin'
 when CompanyUser then '/company'
 end
end
```

Then, refactor the original question views code to this.

```
    <ul class="right">          
            <% if user_signed_in? %>
                <li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
            <% elsif admin_signed_in? %>
                <li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_admin_registration_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Logout", destroy_admin_session_path, method: :delete %></li>       
            <% elsif company_user_signed_in? %>
                <li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_company_user_registration_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Logout", destroy_company_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
            <% else %>
                <% if params[:action] == 'index' %>
                    <li><%= link_to "User Login", new_user_session_path %></li>
                <% elsif params[:action] == 'admin' %>  
                    <li><%= link_to "Admin Login", new_admin_session_path %></li>
                <% else params[:action] == 'company_user' %>
                    <li><%= link_to "Company Login", new_company_user_session_path %></li>
                <% end %>   
            <% end %>   
    </ul>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to nest an `if`/`elsif`/`else` statement inside of an `else` statement as you have done.  You should just continue with the `elsif` statements all the way down to make it clearer and fewer lines of code.